# I want to send data to a php file for processing and receive a response using ajax without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, xml

I want to read and print out tag attribute names from an xml file and print them out on the screen using ajax.The code I wrote in the file_controller.php file works fine in printing the attribute names but the ajax is not fetching the data printed out which is saved in the data array.Please guys I need help in solving this problem.The database files, xml files are all fine.its just the ajax call that is the problem.Thanks in advance

Here is my index.php code for receiving the data

```
<?php 
require('connect.php'); 
?>



<html>
<head>
    <title>Bellcom Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9" style="margin:0 auto; float:none;">
                <span id="message"></span>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Upload files</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class ="form-group">
                        <label>Search for a File Number</label>
                        <input type="text" id="file_name" name="file_name">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" >Fetch</button>
                    </div>

                <div class="table-responsive" id="display" style="display:none">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="10%" align="right"><b>Attribute Name</b></td>
                            <td width="90%"><span id="name"></span></td>
                        </tr>

                         <tr>
                            <td width="10%" align="right"><b>System ID</b></td>
                            <td width="90%"><span id="sysid"></span></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td width="10%" align="right"><b>Date</b></td>
                            <td width="90%"><span id="date"></span></td>
                         </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            var id= $('#file_name').val();
                  if(id != '')
                  {
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url:"file_controller.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data:{id:id},
                        dataType:"JSON",
                        success:function(data)
                            {
                                 $('#meeting_details').css("display", "block");
                                 $('#name').text(data.name);
                                 $('#sysid').text(data.sysid);
                                 $('#date').text(data.date);
                            },
                        error: function (data) {
                          alert("data is not received");
                        }
                    })
                  }else{
                    alert("Please Select a file");
                    $('#meeting_details').css("display", "none");
                  }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is my php file for processing the data.

```
<?php 

require('connect.php'); 

    $f_name = "";


    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $f_name = strip_tags($_POST['id']);//remvove html tags
        $f_name = str_replace(' ', '', $f_name);//remove spaces
        $f_name = strtolower($f_name);//lower case
        $arr = array('XML_','.xml');
        $f_name = implode("$f_name",$arr);

        $database_file = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM xml_files WHERE file_name='$f_name'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($database_file);
        $database_file_name=$row['file_name'];



        if (file_exists("files/$database_file_name")) {
            $xml=simplexml_load_file("$database_file_name") or die("Error: Cannot create object");


            foreach ($xml->children() as $node) {
                foreach ($node->children() as $nodechild) {
                    foreach ($nodechild->children() as $nodegrandchild){
                        $arr = $nodegrandchild->attributes();   // returns an array

                        if (!empty($arr["name"])) {
                            $data['name'] = $arr["name"];   //save the attribute name in an array format 
                            print ("name=".$arr["name"]);     // get the value of this attribute
                            print ("<br>");
                            print ("<p><hr>");
                        }
                        if (!empty($arr["sysid"])) {
                            $data['sysid'] = $arr["sysid"];
                            print ("sysid=".$arr["sysid"]);
                            print ("<br>");
                            print ("<p><hr>");
                        }
                         if (!empty($arr["date"])) {
                            $data['date'] = $arr["date"];
                            print ("date=".$arr["date"]);
                            print ("<br>");                 
                            print ("<p><hr>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    echo json_encode($data);
    }       
 ?>
```

Comment: what does your `data` have in it in ajax call ?

Comment: it is suppose to be the data from the attribute name after extracting it with the attribute() php function.I dont know if you understand me??

Comment: print and see under your success function of ajax if it has required data or not i.e : `alert(data);` .

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `event.preventDefault()`:

```
$('#submit').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault()
```